# Dimension reduction with semi-supervised embeddings

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, nonparametric, semi-supervised-learning

Is there a dimension reduction method (linear or non-linear) where the embeddings/projections of some of the input points are already known in advance and are taken into account during parameter estimation/learning? So, imagine there are 100 points in 10D and we're looking for a 2D representation and for let's say 10 points, we already know 2D coordinates. Is there a method where new 2D projections of 100 points are computed with constraint of getting the same/similar 2D coordinates for these 10 points and consistent coordinates for remaining 90? 
This might be called dimension reduction with semi-supervised embeddings, but I don't know if it exists in the literature.

Edit: "Semi-supervised" in this setting does not refer to class labels, but to projections.